# Lists: Display custom form depending of field value

Tags: list, custom-form, form

In My list I have field called STATUS which can take 4 different values (A,B,C,D), now when user press "Edit" I need to show different Form depending of STATUS (eg Form1 if 'A', Form2 if 'B')

Can you advise how to archive that?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use InfoPath, the form can have multiple view and you can write code behind for this form. On load of the form, the code can check the current value of "Status" and accordingly load the required view.

Comment: Do you have any links with examples demonstrating how to do that in InfoPath? (I understood default 'edit' form must open new Form with desired layout and close itself?)